# export crystal report to sql server report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have one crystal report file , I'm trying to import to a SQLserver report database.

Are there any swift tools I can use , to achieve the results without much hassle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft TechNet offer advice such as this link for Server 2005 :

[Migrating from Business Objects Crystal Reports to SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964127%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) . Unfortunately there does not seem to be one for 2008 but probably little different.